# Laravel , cómo funcionan las tablas creadas en model y MySQL ubicado en el webserver

Tags: laravel

Estoy creando varios MODELs en (laravel), entiendo que cada MODEL me crea mi tabla y en nombre plural de acuerdo al nombre del modelo.
Lo que no sé es si ¿debo de crear las mismas tablas en mi MySQL de mi servidor web?

Gracias a su respuesta a todos chicos

Answer (score 0):

De hecho lo estás haciendo al contrario como lo plantea Laravel:

- Generalmente los modelos van en singular (puedes ver el modelo que incluye el scaffolding: User.php
- Los modelos no crean tablas, las que lo hacen son las migraciones (ver documentación de Laravel)
- No hay necesidad de crear las tablas de forma manual, es un procedimiento largo y aburrido, de nuevo, revisa como las migraciones resuelven este asunto de manera muy sencilla.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, abora cómo se visualiza todas estas tablas en MySQL? Acaso estas tablas aparecen como archvio .frm y no se pueden viualizar...quisiera verlos como el phpAdmin

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres, MySQL es uno solo, si entras por la línea de comando, verás las tablas y puedes hacer todo lo que quieras con tu base de datos. "Visualizar" las tablas de una base de datos no significa usar una herramienta específica. Puedes usar Adminer también.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es si, debes crear las tablas en tu esquema de MySQL, sin embargo, como lo dice Shaz, lo ideal sería dejar que Laravel lo haga creando las migraciones que son el procedimiento estándar de Laravel para crear las tablas.

Con el uso de artisan todo es más sencillo. Por ejemplo:

Para crear un modelo.

```
php artisan make:model (nombre del modelo singular)
```

Para crear una migración (que es como el algoritmo que crea una tabla en la BD):

```
php artisan make:migration create_(nombre de la tabla plural)_table --create=(nombre de la tabla plural)
```

Luego ya en las respectivas carpetas encontraras los archivos creados para realizar las operaciones del modelo y crear las Tablas como sea necesario para tu proyecto

por último, para que la tabla sea creada en la Base de Datos:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Todo esto en detalle lo puedes encontrar en la [Documentación más reciente](http://laravel.com/docs/master)

Comment: Gracias Juandelosantos, una cosa cosa: después de aplicar todo esto cómo puedo ver las tablas en mi base de datos?

Comment: Gracias Juandelsosantos, ...sólo una cosa más: cuando ya he aplicado todo el procedimiento con php artisan migrate debería de tener ya la tabla en MySQL, mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo ver esas tablas? estoy que las busco en el server en la carpeta etc/mysql/...pero no  las hallo...(sólo unos archivos .frm) o ¿Cómo puedo verlos  como se mira en el phmyadmin¿

Comment: bueno, pues ahí puedes entrar a phpmyadmin y consultar tu base de datos o desde el terminal entrar a tu MySQL y ver el contenido de la base de datos:  

  Mira este [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial)

  o este [tutorial](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_database_management.htm)

Comment: Gracias a todos chicos, son de mucha ayuda, abrazos